# Css before backgroud-image won't display, only dispaly if I put it on content, why?

Tags: css, image

I had check, my image load is OK. if I put the image url in content:"url(img/Funny.jpg)", it has no problem, only when I put it in background-image, it won't display, so I tried to put z-index to the before, it failed too. I tried png file, it failed too. The only reason I have to put it to the background-image instead of content because I need to change the image size. I cannot change the content image size. Help,please.

```css
#front_body_button{
 padding:9px;
 position:relative;     
}
#front_body_button #button {
 margin: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
 border-radius:3px;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size: 19px;
        padding: 12px 18px;
 width: 119px;
   background-color:#de614f; 
}
#front_body_button #button:before{
 background-image:url(img/Funny.jpg);
 background-size: 10px 20px;
 width: 10px; 
 height: 20px;
        content:"";
        z-index:9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is by design. Read about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/ tl;dr - pseudo-elements are for inserting *content*, so some content is required.

Comment: @TylerH This isn't true. Content is not required. Clever minds have done many clever things with these new pseudo elements. Look at the clearfix for example.

Comment: @Obsidian While I did misread the question, you are not correct; the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements *will not render* without the `content:` property being declared. I can see how you would misinterpret my original comment, though.

Comment: @TylerH Seems I worded my comment incorrectly too lol. What we mean between us I think is: the `content` tag IS required but does NOT require content within it in order to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::before` elements are not block level.

Add `display:block` to make the height and width viable.

```css
#front_body_button{
  padding:9px;
  position:relative;

}
#front_body_button #button {
  margin: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  width: 119px;
  background-color:#de614f; 
}

#front_body_button #button:before{
  background-image:url(http://mydario.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2014/11/help-dog-picture.jpg);
  background-size: 10px 20px;
  width: 10px; 
  height: 20px;
  content:"";
  z-index:9999 !important;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="front_body_button">
  <div id="button"></div>
</div>
```